# How to make Jquery hasClass check run after using addClass return true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have what I thought would be a simple use case.  I have two parts of a form.  I want to wait until I have part 1 complete before enabling part 2.  So I simply setup an overlay on part 2 that fades out when step 1 is done.

I have a js object that has this method on it:

```
 // Fade In loader or Fade Out loader and overlay
        fadeLoader: function(){
            let loader = $('#entity-step-loader');

            if(loader.hasClass("loader-fade-in")) {
                    console.log('loader fade Out');

                loader.removeClass('loader-fade-in'); 
                $('#entity-step-overlay').fadeOut();

            } else {
                    console.log('loader fade in');

                $('#entity-step-overlay').fadeIn('fast', function(){
                    loader.addClass('loader-fade-in');
                });
            }
        },
```

This method is called in isReadyForStepTwo(). IT is called at the beginning and then again at the end. The reason for this call at both the beginning and the end is that we have to check the entries in step 1 before enabling step 2.  Or the user may decide to change options in step 1 which would involve changing some items in step 2.

the method where this is run twice is:

```
  fieldsToShow: function(){
            console.log('fields to show');
            entity.fadeLoader();

            // Empty identity fields 
            entity.emptyEntity(); 

            // DO A BUNCH OF CHECKING FOR STEP 1 FIELDS

            entity.fadeLoader();
        },
```

This method works  the first time you hit the page. You land on the page, and step 2 has the overlay. When you complete step 2 we show a little loader animation for a second then fade both the loader and the overlay out allowing the person to enter information in the fields.

However if I go back and change options in step 1 the method runs again turning the overlay back on.  But then, like I said above, I run the method at the end again to fade the overlay back out.  This fadeOut is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the `loader-fade-in` class in the `fadeIn` callback "after" the element has "finsihed" fading in:

```
$('#entity-step-overlay').fadeIn('fast', function(){
  loader.addClass('loader-fade-in');
});
```

so when you call `entity.fadeLoader();` the second time it still doesn't have the `loader-fade-in` class and it basically just runs thru the `else` block again.

Try changing it to:

```
$('#entity-step-overlay').fadeIn('fast')
loader.addClass('loader-fade-in');
```

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.  That callback took awhile to get there. thanks